# How to install Visual Studio 2013 community from iso file?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm going to install Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.
Firstly, I downloaded `mu_visual_studio_2013_update_5_x86_dvd_6815499.iso` file in Microsoft's Visual Studio Subscriptions site, and open it.
There are a file and a folder.
file: VS2013.5.exe
folder: packages
When run VS2013.5, it says "*This installation will update all the Visual Studio 2013 products and languages which are currently installed. When complete, this update will use up to **4MB** of disk space.*", even I haven't installed VS2013 on my computer.
I checked registry, and there is no "12.0" prefixed folder or file in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VisualStudio` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC`.
Any helps?

Comment: Did you *try* to install it? Or stopped at the first dialog box? VS takes hundreds of MBs, if not GBs. If the message box says 4MB, it's some update needed by the installer

Comment: Why are you using this 10 year old, totally unsupported version anyway? Why not a recent one? If it's the only version that supports some other obsolete technology, why use *that* ?

Comment: I tried, but there is no new app in my computer. I made a windows C++ library with Visual Studio 2019 (toolset v142) but my client has no choice but to use only Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have downloaded `Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows with Update 5`, not `Visual Studio 2013 Update 5`(I think this has only updated files, not full package).
Inside the right downloaded foler,
file: wdexpress_full.exe
folder: packages